# Shell Scripting finding text in a text file

Tags: string, shell, scripting, sed

i am trying to check for a string in a text file.  If string1 does not exisit then add string1 after string 2.  Else string1 exists do nothing.

Here is what i have so far:

```
if [ string1 does not exisit ]  //Stuck at this
then
sed '/string2/ a\ string1' myfile
fi
```

Also how can include the "/" character in my strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if grep -qs string1 myfile
then
    sed '/string1/ a\ string2' myfile
fi
```

However, you could skip the `if` since `sed` is testing for the existence of the string anyway. That way, you're only reading the file once instead of twice. Use `sed -i` if you want the change to be made to the file in-place.

Comment: Sorry i made a typo, sed should be checking for the existence of string2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`, for example like this :

```
$(grep -q "string1" myfile)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    sed '/string1/ a\ string2' myfile
fi
```

Comment: The brackets and command substitution aren't necessary. The `-eq 1` won't pass because the exit code is not output, it's held in `$?`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'll modify the code. Concerning the bracket, I like to put them even if they aren't necessary, I find the code more readable with them.